# Snapshotting modal view controller on iPad gets nonround corners

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I making a composition of whole window hierarchy including modal view controller using snapshots, but when i get snapshot of modal VC (form sheet) it have corner radius = 0. Although view controller that presented on screen have rounded corners. How to get corner radius of modal view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `cornerRadius` of `view's` `layer` to a required value and also set `clipsToBounds` to `true`, i.e.

```
self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
self.view.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Its exact value for corner radius of form sheet modal VC?

Comment: You can give the value as per your requirement. `20.0` is just an example.